# Regex parsing in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Can you help how to parse the regex i have tried a lot but not able to do.

Input : `<a onclick="javascript:collapse('displayText','hideText','whyInfo-arrow-image')"><span sd:text="${whyInfoLabel}">Learn more about Authentication</span>  <img id="whyInfo-arrow-image" sd:src="${downwardArrowImage}" height="20" width="20" >`

Expected : `sd:text="${whyInfoLabel}"`
and `sd:src="${downwardArrowImage}"`

My attempt 1 :  `"/\$\{(\w*)\}/g"`  it can pick only `{whyInfoLabel}` & `{downwardArrowImage}`

My attempt 2 : `"/sd.*\$\{(\w*)\}/g"` this is not able to split.

I am very new to Regex and to JavaScript.

Any help will be great.

Comment: This is one of the famous type questions, unfortunately... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: You're in JS, why don't you use the DOM to parse HTML instead?

Answer (score 1):

You're in JS, why don't you use the DOM to parse HTML instead? Regex isn't designed to parse HTML, but the DOM provides a utility that is designed specifically for that purpose.

If your [browser supports it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=xml-serializer), you should consider doing this using the [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) instead:

```
var html = "<a onclick=\"javascript:collapse('displayText','hideText','whyInfo-arrow-image')\"><span sd:text=\"${whyInfoLabel}\">Learn more about Authentication</span>  <img id=\"whyInfo-arrow-image\" sd:src=\"${downwardArrowImage}\" height=\"20\" width=\"20\" >";

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");

var attrText = doc.querySelector('span').getAttribute("sd:text");
console.log(attrText);

var attrSrc = doc.querySelector('img').getAttribute("sd:src");
console.log(attrSrc);
```

> "${whyInfoLabel}"
>   "${downwardArrowImage}"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`/(sd:.*=".*")/Ug`

Or this:
`/\{(.*)\}/Ug`

Answer (score 0):

This should give you both results in an array:

```
/sd:(?:text|src)=\"[^\"]*"/g
```

The regex matches 'sd:' at start, followed by 'text' or 'src', a equal sign, a double quote followed by zero or more characters not being a double quote, and finally a double quote.

Just call (assuming your text in a variable called `'text'`:

```
var regex =/sd:(?:text|src)=\"[^\"]*"/g;
var matches = text.match(regex);
var match0 = matches[0];
var match1 = matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex. Hope this helps.

```js
const regex = /\w+:\w+="\$\{\w*\}"/g;

const input = '<a onclick="javascript:collapse(' + 'displayText' + ',' + 'hideText' + ','+ 'whyInfo-arrow-image' + ')"><span sd:text="${whyInfoLabel}">Learn more about Authentication</span>  <img id="whyInfo-arrow-image" sd:src="${downwardArrowImage}" height="20" width="20" >';

console.log(input.match(regex))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
asdf = new RegExp('(sd:.+?[}])+', 'gi');
console.log(str.match(asdf));
```

Answer (score 0):

more general:

```
(?<=["\s])[^\s]+?\s?=\s?"\$\{(?:\w*)\}"
```

[REGEX 101](https://regex101.com/r/6zp0mZ/1)